# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String, Double)'

Tags: swift, ios9

My code was working perfectly fine with iOS 8, now I've updated to 9 and xcode is throwing this error at me.

Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String, Double)'

```
var stockDetails: [(String,Double)] = [("Microsoft",128.0), ......

let valueStringClean: NSString = (valueString as NSString).substringToIndex(valueString.characters.count-1)

stockDetails.append("\(stockName)", valueStringClean.doubleValue)
```

I'm not very fluent in Swift and curious what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a tuple, So you need to add "(...)" in append method, some thing like that:

```
var stockDetails: [(String,Double)] = [("a",1),("b",2)]
let valueString = "SomeString"
let valueStringClean: NSString = (valueString as  NSString).substringToIndex(valueString.characters.count-1)
stockName = "AnotherString"
```

You will change next line to be like that:

```
stockDetails.append(("\(stockName)", valueStringClean.doubleValue))
```